# Pausing / resuming Dropbox from the command line (Windows)

Tags: windows, dropbox

Is there a way to pause and resume Dropbox from the command line?

I'm running Dropbox as a normal installation (no Windows Service)

I don't want to `KILL` or freeze the Dropbox process. I want it to go to 'Suspended' mode like it does when clicking on 'Pause syncing'.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli is worth a dev investigating to add the feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that Dropbox on Windows does not offer command line options to pause and resume.

What I found effective is to actually suspend the Dropbox process. One way to do that is to use *sysinternals* utility [pssuspend](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pssuspend.aspx)

Once that's available in the default search path, one can issue commands from the commandline like

> pssuspend Dropbox

to suspend the Dropbox process and

> pssuspend -r Dropbox

to resume it.

At the beginning I was worried that Dropbox would fail to synchronize files changed while Dropbox process was suspended but it seems that the file-system change notifications are queued up correctly.

Comment: This seemed like a great end around, but it's not working for me on Win10. Dropbox suspends just fine, but resuming it doesn't kick off another sync. Tried with changing files and adding new ones to the folder while suspended and nothing got sync'd.

Comment: @Mordred Fixed  as of 2023, either Dropbox or Microsoft fixed it. New/changed files immediately sync for me upon resume. It's a great way to make Dropbox sync more "atomic", if you're doing a scripted task that churns a folder very aggressively and you don't want Dropbox to waste time syncing until the end.  I was searching for a solution and pssuspend was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create an outbound rule in the firewall and then turn it on and off in a batch file:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Dropbox" new enable=yes
```

and

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Dropbox" new enable=no
```

Comment: This will cut the Dropbox process' network activity. Unfortunately that won't help. I need the Dropbox process to stop accessing files.

Answer (score 1):

At the time being (DropBox for Windows version 3.4.4) there is NO command line available (except for "/home" that opens the dropbox folder).
There is a request on dropbox forum to add it, but the company has not added it yet